# SQL Server inserts value even if SET PARSEONLY is set to ON

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

Can someone explain me why the first statement inserts a value into the database and the second statement does not insert a value.
Server is a SQL-Server 2014

First Statement:

```
SET PARSEONLY ON;
go
Insert Into DKO
(AUF_NR) values (42);
--go
SET PARSEONLY OFF;
go

Select top 10 auf_nr from dko where AUF_NR = 42
```

Second Statement:

```
SET PARSEONLY ON;
go
Insert Into DKO
(AUF_NR) values (42);
go
SET PARSEONLY OFF;
go

Select top 10 auf_nr from dko where AUF_NR = 42
```

The only difference between the two statements is the go keyword at the end of the insert statement.

Comment: It looks like without "GO" SQL SETs PARSEONLY OFF during compilation time of the statement and obviously because it is OFF, executes the statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178629.aspx) "The setting of SET PARSEONLY is set at parse time and not at execute or run time.". Important point to remember is that GO (on it's own at the start of a line) is the batch separator.

In your first example, the first batch sets PARSEONLY ON, the second batch turns it off and executes the INSERT statement. In the second example, the first batch turns it on, the second batch is the parsed-only INSERT statement, the third batch turns it off.